# Java incorrect JSON Result

Tags: java, android, json

i have an issue with getting incorrect JSON result from intent; it comes like the following `{StartDateTime=20201115101843, amount=1111, terminalId=1234567812121250}`, instead of `{"StartDateTime":"20201112102410", "amount":"777", "terminalId":"1234567812121250"}`, i was pass the values as the following :

```
intent.putExtra("StartDateTime", pubBean.getFirstReceiptDatetime());                 
put(ThirdTag.AMOUNT, water.getAmount());
intent.putExtra("Terminal ID", pubBean.getPosID());
```

please advice?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow please reframe your questions and highlight code by selecting then pressing ctrl+k

Comment: Why do you believe that `intent.putExtra()` has anything to do with JSON? It doesn't. If you want JSON, you need to use the JSON API. [`Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent) doesn't give that to you for free.

Comment: Good point.  That looks like what you get from `HashMap.toString()` ... for example ... which is not *intended* to be JSON.

Comment: Stephen C- String getFirstReceiptDatetime(), Long getAmount, String getPosID()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your data model looks like but this is a simple example :

- Pass the JSONObject :

  ```
  JSONObject data = new JSONObject("{\"StartDateTime\":\"20201112102410\", \"amount\":\"777\", \"terminalId\":\"1234567812121250\"}");

  Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("data", data.toString());
  startActivity(intent);
  ```

Then get the value in other Activity :

```
JSONObject dataFromFirtstActivity = new JSONObject(getIntent().getStringExtra("data"));
```

- Pass the specific value :

  ```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("startDateTime", data.getLong("startDateTime"));
  intent.putExtra("amount", data.getInt("amount"));
  intent.putExtra("terminalId", data.getString("terminalId"));
  startActivity(intent);
  ```

Then get the value in other Activity :

```
  long startDateTime = getIntent().getLongExtra("startDateTime", 0);
  int amount = getIntent().getIntExtra("amount", 0);
  String terminalId = getIntent().getStringExtra("terminalId");
```

You should deal with your **data** first before going any further, and you can read more about passing data in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)